# ASP.NET Convert money datatype to displayable value on screen

Tags: asp.net

Just pulled from database a value from DB with datatype and appearing on my screen as

9.8600

Whats best way to get this to get to

€9.86

Comment: you just need to pass it the format specifier, and an optional precision.  See my answer below.

Comment: do you still need any assistance with this? In addition, what is the status of this question?

Answer (score 2):

Pass it to ToString with a `c` you can optionally add an integer after the letter c for the precision.  If I wanted 2 digits after the decimal `"c2"`

```
valueFromDB.ToString("c")
```

For C#:

```
decimal value = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:C2}.", value);
// Displays "Your account balance is $123.46."
```

For VB:

```
Dim value As Decimal = 123.456d
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:C2}.", value)
' Displays "Your account balance is $123.46."
```

If in doubt, MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

[image]